# Unit testing error System.InvalidCastException:

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core

I'm testing a method that calls a function from my repository and returns it as a list but I keep getting this error:

> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]' to type 'System.String[]'.

I don't know what I'm missing. Here's the method:

```
public IList<TransactionStatus> GetBookingStatuses(IList<string> uniqueTransactionRefs)
{
    TransactionStatus[] transactionStatuses = DBRepository.GetStatuses((string[])uniqueTransactionRefs);
    return transactionStatuses;
}
```

And this is the method `GetStatuses` in my repository:

```
TransactionStatus[] GetStatuses(string[] uniqueTransactionRefs);
```

Comment: I think you need to pass uniqueTransactionRefs to the GetStatuses method.

Answer (score 1):

`IList<string>` is an interface that both string array (`string[]`) and string lists (`List<string>`) implements. That means that it is a good candidate to receive multiple strings regardless of which underlying data type is being used.

In your case, your method `GetBookingStatuses` receives the data as an `IList<string>` but as you can see from the error message, the actual type of `uniqueTransactionRefs` is `` System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String] ``, i.e. `List<string>`. Since this is a valid `IList<string>`, passing the data to the method works fine. But when you then try to cast it to a string array, it will fail because the `List<string>` is not directly compatible to `string[]`.

There are two options for fixing this:

- You could convert the `List<string>` explicitly to a string array by calling `.ToArray()` on it. This will create a new string array with the elements from the source list:

  ```
  TransactionStatus[] transactionStatuses = DBRepository.GetStatuses(uniqueTransactionRefs.ToArray());
  ```
- Depending on what your `GetStatuses` method does, you could also change its signature that it does not require a string array but also take an `IList<string>`. Then you could pass in the `uniqueTransactionRefs` from the `GetBookingStatuses` directly without having to convert it:

  ```
  TransactionStatus[] transactionStatuses = DBRepository.GetStatuses(uniqueTransactionRefs);
  ```

  ```
  public TransactionStatus[] GetStatuses(IList<string> uniqueTransactionRefs)
  {
      // …
  }
  ```

Comment: Huh, interesting, I'd have thought that `ToArray()` on a `List<T>` would be optimized to just return the underlying array rather than copying it, but the source code says you're right

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Afaik, `ToArray()` will always create a new array so that you can use it to quickly get a safe copy of the array that cannot be mutated by the original source.